# How to resolve "Unhandled Runtime Error" "TypeError: videoRef.current.play is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to add custom controls to a video on a Nextjs site. If I use a regular HTML `<video>` component, my code works and clicking the custom play button plays the video, but if I use the `<ReactPlayer>` component instead, I get the TypeError;

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: videoRef.current.play is not a function
```

Here is the code of my Video component;

```
import videoStyles from '../styles/video.module.css'
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRef } from 'react'
import bigPlayImg from '../public/images/purchased-class_play_button.svg'
import playImg from '../public/images/class_details_video_play_icon.svg'
import forwardImg from '../public/images/browse_filters_right_arrow-arrow_carrot-left.svg'
import backImg from '../public/images/browse_filters_left_arrow-arrow_carrot-left.svg'

export default function Video() {
  
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const videoHandler = (control) => {
    if (control === "play") {
      videoRef.current.play();
    } else if (control === "pause") {
      videoRef.current.pause();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReactPlayer
        ref={videoRef}
        className={videoStyles.video}
        url='/videos/samplevideo.mp4'
        width='800px'
        height='404px'
        type='video/mp4'
        light='/images/class_overview_video@1x.png'
        playing
        controls

        playIcon={
          <Image
            src={bigPlayImg}
            alt="play icon"
            className={videoStyles.playIcon}
            width={73}
            height={73}
          />
        }
      />

    {/* <video
        ref={videoRef}
        className="video"
        src='/videos/samplevideo.mp4'
    ></video> */}

      <div className={videoStyles.controlsContainer}>
        <div className={videoStyles.controls}>
          <Image
            src={backImg}
            className={videoStyles.controlsIcon}
            alt="back icon"
          />
          <Image
            src={playImg}
            onClick={() => videoHandler("play")}
            className={videoStyles.controlsIconSmall}
            alt="play icon"
          />
          <Image
            src={forwardImg}
            className={videoStyles.controlsIcon}
            alt="forward icon"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={videoStyles.timecontrols}>
        <p className={videoStyles.controlsTime}>1:02</p>
        <div className={videoStyles.timeProgressbarContainer}>
          <div style={{ width: "40%" }} className={videoStyles.timeProgressBar}></div>
        </div>
        <p className={videoStyles.controlsTime}>2:05</p>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

According to the [react-player page on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player), you should be able to use the ref prop to call instance methods on the player (such as .play() ), just like you would on a regular html `<video>` component;
"Use ref to call instance methods on the player. See the demo app for an example of this."

I've tried;

- Stripping all the props from the `<ReactPlayer>` component, except
  for the essentials that are on the `<video>` component (ref,
  className and src/url).
- Updating all packages
- Ripping my hair out

How do I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've read in the documentation you've provided in your question, the package does not provide a `play()` instance method but rather a prop called `playing`. You could use it like this:

> `playing`: Set to true or false to pause or play the media

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

export default function App() {
 const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false); // or true for autoplay
 return (
   <>
     <Button onClick={() => setPlaying(true)} />
     <ReactPlayer playing={playing} />
   </>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I tried that and it does not work. It does not produce an error, but neither does it make the video play.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the local instance of a video with a YouTube video to test if it works that way? Because I suspect that the library is unable to locate the video with the provided path.

Comment: I didn't think of that, thank you. I tried it but got the same error.